# gcc-7 for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compiling, gcc, lts

Since I would like to play around with C++17 and several TSs I am searching to install GCC 7.0 on my Ubuntu 16.04.

Sadly I could not yet find a version out there which would not produce colliding package dependencies.

I generally settled for LTS and am not in the mood to upgrade to later versions. Thus is there another option than compiling GCC from source?

Comment: If you just want to play around, wait a little. The [toolchain test PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) has GCC 7 for 17.04 (which isn't building fully successfully now), so it might take a few days for it to become available for 16.04 and older releases.

Comment: The question to me is more whether anyone is actually porting that back to 16.04. Why do you assume that it only takes a few days?

Comment: I didn't assume that. Note: "it *might" ...'

Comment: @muru gcc-trunk (gcc-7)  is usually only on ubuntu-dev (17.04). As soon as gcc releases 7.0, it is usually backported to stable ubuntu versions. In the mean time, you have to build from source.