# Installing gcc-7 (and newer packages) in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, ppa, gcc

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I want to install a newer version of GCC, specifically gcc-7 which released [May 2, 2017](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html). There is a package for it in the [Toolchain test builds ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test), but the Ubuntu version listed next to it is `7-20170407-0ubuntu2` (I have no idea what this corresponds to). I tried following the instructions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859256/how-to-install-gcc-7-or-clang-4-0)  and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849120/gcc-7-for-ubuntu-16-04) and had the same issues. They are from before gcc 7.1 officially had a release, so I am not sure if the instructions would change at all now that it is out?

Even after adding the ppa I get the following:

```
user@computer:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
user@computer:~$ sudo apt-get update
user@computer:~$ sudo apt install gcc-7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-7
```

Any idea on how I can install the new gcc? I am not looking to upgrade my distribution. I am also not above building from source, however that is kind of my last resort because managing that all by hand is just annoying.

Comment: The gcc-7 package in the PPA is only for 17.04. It's not been long since GCC 7.1 came out, so I'd guess it'd come soon.

Comment: @muru Got it, thanks! I guess I'll be compiling from source in the mean time. Oh well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the package in question is now available in this PPA for Xenial.

Answer (score 8):

You can already install gcc-7 and g++-7 from [this package](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7
```

Comment: Are there any official ppa? https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y software-properties-common build-essential g++-multilib && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt install -y gcc-7-multilib g++-7-multilib Should get a freshly installed 16.04 system up to speed with gcc 7, all you have to do then is change the gcc/g++ symbolic links

Answer (score 1):

Type:

```
sudo sed -i 's/xenial/zesty/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r*.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

And you will have installed `gcc` `gcc-7` `cpp` `cpp-7` `g++` `g++-7` and few additional dependencies packages in your current Ubuntu release (not older 16.04).